# jQuery trigger change on class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a list of checkboxes. Each checkbox has `.change(function(){alert('xyz')})`. Each checkbox has a class `abc`.
I also have an additional checkbox called 'ALL'. When the 'ALL' checkbox is changed, it changes the state of all the other checkboxes.

I would like the change of the 'ALL' checkbox to trigger the change (`.change(...)`) of all the other checkboxes. But since the state of the other checkboxes is done programmatically, it doesn't work by itself.

I've tried to use `$('.abc').change()` to trigger the change event of all the checkboxes, but it didn't work.

What am I doing wrong, and how can the task at hand be achieved ?
BTW, if I do `$('#id_of_a_specific_checkbox').change()` it works great.

**UPDATE**
Example of what I have:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZqJvc/

It's pretty much what I have in the large project... And in the short example it works :/
But in the real project it doesn't work. The only difference is that in the real project I have lots of checkboxes. Weird... I guess it's back to the debugger.

**UPDATE**
After Chrome crashed completely... I restarted the browser and it just worked as in the example above. Sorry wasting our time.

Comment: Use trigger() jquery function. .trigger('change')

Comment: Can you not do `$(".abc").each(function () { $(this).change(); });`

Comment: Why would you need to trigger the change event for all the checkboxes? If you're trying to actually change the state that would be done with prop(). anyway : `$('.abc').each(function() {$(this).trigger('change');});`

Comment: Why did `$('.abc').change()` not work, any errors? Show us the code and/or set up a small demo.

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/9zYN8/

Comment: @Meliborn I've tried `.trigger('change')`, it didn't work.

Comment: @mattytommo just tried `$(".abc").each(function () { $(this).change(); })` no reaction.<br/>

Comment: @Meliborn `$('.abc').click()` crashed Chrome :)

Comment: @Bergi zero errors. clean console.
update: due to Chrome's crash before I reloaded the page and got this error: `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set all checkboxes with the .abc class to true when the ALL checkbox changes use

```
$("input[name=ALL]").change( function( ) {

    $(".abc").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked") );
    $(".abc").trigger("change");
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Xa7QK/)

Comment: Thanks. But only changes the state of the checkboxes but doesn't trigger their change event.

Comment: as others pointer it in the comments under the question, it's one of the options and I should work... And it does, in a simplified example http://jsfiddle.net/9zYN8/ But no in my actual project... I guess I'll to break it apart and search for the reason behind the issue. Thanks again.